# Como usar 2-d numpy array com interativo com FloatSlider do panel para um plot de imagem em python?

Tags: python, numpy, plot, slider, panel

Usando holloviews e panel.
Como criar uma função que receba como argumentos um np.array (2d, uma matriz) e um "corte de valores". Retorne o 2d array plotado como imagem? Sendo o que que o argumento "corte de valores" deve ser interativo (um FloatSlider).

Tentei de alguns jeitos, mas sempre que coloco o 2d array como argumento da função da um erro ex:

**** Tentativa 1 ****

Retorna erro:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

###################

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('bokeh')
import panel as pn
pn.extension()


mat = np.random.rand(50,50) #2d array

slider = pn.widgets.FloatSlider(start=0.0, end=2.0, value=0.5, name='Cota de Corte: ') #cria ao widget


def plota_imagem (M, slider_corte):

    corte = np.where(M <= slider_corte, M, np.nan)
    img = hv.Image(corte)
    return img


pn.interact(plota_imagem, M=mat, slider_corte=slider )
```

**** Tentativa 2 ****

Desta forma funciona, mas o 2d array não está como argumento da função e preciso que esteja.

```
##################

slider = pn.widgets.FloatSlider(start=0.0, end=1.0, value=0.5, name='Cota de Corte: ')

mat = np.random.rand(50,50) #2d array

def plota_imagem (slider_corte):

    corte = np.where(mat<=slider_corte, mat, np.nan)
    img = hv.Image(corte)
    return img

pn.interact(plota_imagem,slider_corte=slider )

#####################
```

Existe alguma solução para que a Tentativa 1 funcione, ou seja, o array 2d (mat) seja também um argumento da função?

Answer (score 0):

Imports:

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('bokeh')
import panel as pn
pn.extension()
```

A maneira que encontrei foi passando como um parâmetro direto na sua função plota_imagem:

```
mat = np.random.rand(50,50)
slider = pn.widgets.FloatSlider(start=0.0, end=2.0, value=0.5, name='Cota de Corte: ') 

def plota_imagem (slider_corte, M = mat):

    corte = np.where(M <= slider_corte, M, np.nan)
    img = hv.Image(corte)
    return img

pn.interact(plota_imagem,slider_corte = slider)
```

Dessa forma qualquer valor de um np.random.rand que você passar vai direto pra função.

> `def plota_imagem (slider_corte, M = mat)`

Saída:

[image: Saída]